# How to reliably identify leaking DOM nodes in a web app with Chrome Dev Tools (.. or any other tool)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

An example, these Snapshots and Performance Profile were produced with Chrome Dev Tools like this:

Using Chrome 66.0 on macOS 10.13.4. All Chrome extension off, all console logging disabled, running in Incognito mode.

- GC few times
- Take snapshot #1
- Start performance profiling
- Do Thing 3 times
- GC few times
- Do Thing 3 times
- GC few times
- .. wait for a long time so that listeners can be GCd ..
- GC few times
- Stop performance profiling
- Take snapshot #2

[image]

[image]

I can reproduce the issue consistently with the node counts in the Performance Profile increasing by the same amount every time.

Why does the Performance Profile show that the node count never returns to the original level, but Snapshots do not show any new nodes?

Is there any way (without trial and error) to find what those nodes are?

Does Firefox (or some other browser or tool) have any similar tool for detecting leaking nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to upgrade to Chrome Canary (v69.0 is what was available now), with that nodes counts return to original levels after GCs.

Chrome v66.0 apparently has some issues with keeping count of nodes. Stable Chrome also just upgraded itself for me and v67.0 has the same issue.